# Top 10 branches which had higher sales in February than January

Tags: sql-server

I need to show a result of the top 10 branches of a store, which have seen greater monthly sales in February than January.

My columns look like this -

```
BranchID
SaleDate
SaleAmount
```

I tried partitioning by both branchid and the month of salesdate, but I'm not sure how to incorporate grouping along with partitioning.

```
select branchid, 
       datepart(month, saledate) as month, 
       sum(saleamount) over (partition by datepart(month, saledate), branchid  order by saledate) as 'Monthly Sales' 
from sales
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the top 10 highest increase from Jan to Feb in sales, here is one way that you could do this below.

```
SELECT TOP(10) --Get top 10
        [BranchID],
        ISNULL(SUM(
            CASE WHEN MONTH([SaleDate]) = 2
            THEN [SaleAmount]
            ELSE 0 END
        ),0) as [SaleAmountFeb], --Sum all Feb sales
        ISNULL(SUM(
            CASE WHEN MONTH([SaleDate]) = 1
            THEN [SaleAmount]
            ELSE 0 END
        ),0) as [SaleAmountJan], --Sum all Jan sales

        ISNULL(SUM(
            CASE WHEN MONTH([SaleDate]) = 2
            THEN [SaleAmount]
            ELSE 0 END
        ),0) - 
        ISNULL(SUM(
            CASE WHEN MONTH([SaleDate]) = 1
            THEN [SaleAmount]
            ELSE 0 END
        ),0) as [Increase in Sales] --Increase in sales Jan to Feb

    FROM sales
    GROUP BY
        [BranchID]
    ORDER BY
        4 DESC --Order by Increase in sales Jan to Feb (Largest to smallest)
```